# NHibernate Bi-directional ManyToMany Relationship Caching Issue

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I got issue with bi-directional ManyToMany relationship caching

First side mapping :

```
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Jobs)
            .Table("ProfileSuggestStoryJob")
            .AsSet()
            .Cascade.None()
            .ParentKeyColumn("ProfileSuggestStoryId")
            .ChildKeyColumn("JobId")
            .Cache.ReadWrite();
```

Second side mapping :

```
        HasManyToMany(x => x.SuggestedProfiles)
            .Table("ProfileSuggestStoryJob")
            .AsSet()
            .Cascade.None()
            .ParentKeyColumn("JobId")
            .ChildKeyColumn("ProfileSuggestStoryId")
            .Inverse().Cache.ReadWrite();
```

The first side is responsible for the insert/update/delete, entites are well stored. But on the second side the cache is not updated, and the collection don't contains the recently added entity.

Without cache, all is working fine ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each side of the relationship has its own cache; NHibernate will not invalidate the cache of the second side because of changes in the first side.

You can use `SessionFactory.EvictCollection` to invalidate it manually.